# Matrix Form for Hitting Probabilities in a Markov Chain

Tags: probability, markov-chains

I've just read that the vector of hitting probabilities $h^A=\left(h^A_i=P(H^A<\infty|X_0=i):i \in S\right)$ is the minimal solution to the linear system:

$h^A_i=1, i \in A$ and $h^A_i=\sum_{j \in S} p_{ij}h^A_j, i \notin A$

Is there a way to write this in matrix form? And how can we be sure that such a solution exists for this linear system?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $P_Ah^A=h^A$ where rows $i$ of $P_A$ for $i\in A$, $P_A^{ij}=\delta_{ij}$ and $P^{ij}$ otherwise.

Comment: @A.S. shouldn't we also change h^A, otherwise for $i \in A, h^A_i=h^A_i $, which is different from what is written above. Also, I was also trying to state this problem without changing the matrix P. Just using multiplications and sums of matrices.

Comment: The vector with all ones is a solution.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland but it's not minimal, since $h^A_i$ are probabilities. It's the maximal solution. How do I know that a minimum solution exists?

Comment: Sorry, I misread "a solution" for "such a solution."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matrix form:

$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{cccccc|c}
      1&0&0&0&0&0&1\\
      0&1&0&0&0&0&1\\
      0&0&1&0&0&0&1\\
&&&\cdots &&& 1\\
      p_{i,0} & p_{i,1} & \cdots & p_{i,i}-1 & p_{i,i+1} & \cdots & 0 \\
      p_{i+1,0} & p_{i+1,1} & \cdots & p_{i,i} & p_{i+1,i+1}-1 & \cdots & 0 \\
&&\cdots &&&& 0\\
      p_{n,0} & p_{n,1} & \cdots & \cdots & p_{n,n-1} & p_{n,n}-1 & 0 \\
    \end{array}
\right] $$

To see that the $h_i^A$'s are a solution:

Firstly, if $i\in A$ then $X_0=i\implies H^A=0\implies h_i^A=1$.

Suppose now that $i\notin A$. Conditioning on the first step:

\begin{align}
h_i^A &= \sum_{j\in S}P(X_1=j\mid X_0=i) P(H^A\lt\infty|X_1=j,X_0=i) \\
&= \sum_{j\in S}p_{ij} P(H^A\lt\infty|X_0=j) \qquad\text{since, given $X_0=i\notin A$, we know $H_A\neq 0$} \\
&= \sum_{j\in S}p_{ij} h_j^A \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\text{(1)} 
\end{align}

If you want to see why this solution is minimal, take an arbitrary solution $s_1,s_2,\ldots,s_n$.

For $i\in A$ we must have $s_i=1=h_i$ so minimality for such $i$ holds trivially.

Suppose now that $i\notin A$. Then our equation (1) for $s_i$ can be split into separate sums, and then at each step iterate by replacing the $s_j$ values:

\begin{align}
s_i &= \sum_{j\in A}p_{ij} + \sum_{j\notin A}p_{ij} s_j \qquad\text{using $s_j=1$ for $j\in A$} \\
&= P(H_A\leq 1\mid X_0=i) + \sum_{j\notin A}p_{ij} s_j \\
&= P(H_A\leq 1\mid X_0=i) + \sum_{j_1\notin A}p_{ij_1} \left(\sum_{j\in A}p_{j_1j} + \sum_{j_2\notin A}p_{j_1 j_2} s_{j_2}\right) \\
&= P(H_A\leq 2\mid X_0=i) + \sum_{j_1\notin A}p_{ij_1} \left(\sum_{j_2\notin A}p_{j_1 j_2} s_{j_2}\right) \\
& \ldots \\
\end{align}

Continuing in this way, we have, for arbitrarily large $M$,

\begin{align}
s_i &= P(H_A\leq M\mid X_0=i) \;+\; \text{some non-negative term} \\
\therefore\quad s_i &\geq P(H_A\lt\infty\mid X_0=i) = h_i^A \qquad\text{which proves minimality.}
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mick. Your answer is very good, but I think it doesn't deal with one of my doubts, namely the second one. The reason why I asked how one would write the linear system was to understand if we could say, in the case of having an infinite amount of solutions, if the minimal solution existed. How can we be sure that the minimal solution exists?

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. I think I showed that it exists not via the matrix but via the derivation of equations (1). The $h_i^A$s all exist - they're probabilities - so (1) must be satisfied by them - unless there's a mistake in my derivation. :-) Whether or not other solutions exists could be solved by other means, matrix or otherwise. The last part shows there are no other solutions "less" than it.

Comment: Yes of course. I'm sorry.

Comment: Mick, may I interest you in another of my questions? 

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1572134/chuck-norris-coupling-of-markov-chains-an-invariant-distribution

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. Note that the minimality of the $h_i$s is only with respect to non-negative solutions to the given system of equations. It doesn't say anything about the existence of solutions with negative values. This is because of the final term in the lines above where we assume all $s_i$s are non-negative so that the sum they are in is non-negative.